# Optimizing realloc function

Tags: c

I am writing a realloc function and currently my realloc handles two cases (not counting the null cases)

1. If enough memory exists next to the block, expand it
2. else allocate a new block and do a memcpy

My question is, are there any more cases I should be handling? I can't think of any.

I thought of a case where the previous block maybe free and to expand my earlier block forward, but that would require a memcpy, so it would be pointless implementing that.

Comment: Is that an exercise (be it self-imposed or homework)? Any stdlib's realloc should already behave so. I haven't encountered one yet which doesn't. Regarding the question, you have covered all cases I can think of.

Comment: Consider the 'same size' case - not very likely, but make sure nothing breaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include the case where the new size is smaller than the old size; ideally you should split your current block and make the end of it free.

Comment: Yes this is part of an assignment. Thank you for reminding me about the case where the re-sizing decreases the size of a block. I will try that out and see how much my memory utilization increases (my professor has a test for utilization and throughput).

Answer (score 1):

Messing around with memory allocation routines is extremely risky; most are already as optimized as they physically can be, without impacting security. Any optimizations you may do may very well open up a hole that can be exploited - there are many 'use after free' style security issues around at the moment.

With this in mind, where better to look than the OpenBSD source for it: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/stdlib/malloc.c?rev=1.140;content-type=text%2Fx-cvsweb-markup

Answer (score 0):

There are those cases where the realloc reduces the block size by a non-trivial amount that is worth reclaiming for allocation elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could strive towards optimising `realloc` for performance (i.e. avoid moving the block and the `memcpy`), or you could optimise against memory fragmentation.

If it's the latter, you may consider moving the block to fill the best gap instead of just expanding or shrinking it.

Memory allocators are always a trade-off.